# Read Google Maps Notifications via NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, google-maps, notification-listener

Is it possible to read, Google Maps navigation notification which are shown periodically as the user moves?

For example the distance remaining from next turn is periodically updated. I tried using the NotificationListenerService for this but the notifications generated by Google Maps don't have any of that information when I try using the method getNotifications().getExtras().

Usually notifications published by messaging apps like Whatsapp have everything that one needs in the extras hashmap but Google map doesn't. Is there a possible workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: you got answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

From Oreo: 
`statusBarNotification.getNotification().getExtras()` returns a Bundle with the navigation information.

Before Oreo:
It's more tricky as the information is found inside the RemoteViews included in the notification.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [simple free library](https://github.com/3v1n0/GMapsParser) that you can use to parse Google Maps notifications and get those values.

You can easily get them by implementing a `NavigationListener` yourself.