# ANDROID: Implement Google Maps direction in my app

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, directions

I would like to add to an app the directions from the Google maps as seen bellow, but the information to come from the google maps when I am starting the navigation (a route on the main Maps App. Would that be possible? And if yes, where would I start?
[image]

EDIT: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328657/read-google-maps-notifications-via-notificationlistenerservice) describes better the issue I'm having, and it even provides a [Kotlin library](https://github.com/3v1n0/GMapsParser)  that can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using the notification Listener Service. There is a [Kotlin library](https://github.com/3v1n0/GMapsParser)  that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mapbox API for Navigation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/). It's a very great library to use.

Check this [tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-navigation-sdk/) for implementation.

Check the example that you want exactly.

[Basic UI Navigation Example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/examples/basic-nav-ui-sdk/)

[BETA => Turn-by-turn navigation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/beta/navigation/examples/basic/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I want is to use the already opened GoogleMaps app to retrieve the directions information and to implement them in my app (to show only some direction arrow, the distance to the next intersection --> like in the dashboard of the new vehicles). I do not want to build a new navigation app.